# Java - Blank window

Tags: java

I am newbie to Java. My following code give me a blank window.

Anyone can help me with what is going on ?

I am thinking that the error is at the ActionListeners.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Listeners"); 
        frame.setSize(400, 200); 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true); 
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 

        JTextArea txtArea = new JTextArea();
        HelloActionListener hlisten = new HelloActionListener(txtArea); 
        JButton bl = new JButton("TOP"); 
        bl.addActionListener((ActionListener) hlisten); 
        JButton b2 = new JButton("LEFT"); 
        ActionListener rightListener = (ActionEvent e) -> {
            txtArea.setText("Yes,let's go Left");
        }; 
    b2.addActionListener(rightListener); 
    JButton b3 = new JButton("RIGHT"); 
    b3.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
                txtArea.setText("Sorry, we cant go Right");
        });

    JButton b4 = new JButton("Bottom"); 
    b4.addActionListener((ActionListener) hlisten);

    frame.add(bl, BorderLayout.PAGE_START); 
    frame.add(b2, BorderLayout.LINE_START); 
    frame.add(b3, BorderLayout.LINE_END); 
    frame.add(b4, BorderLayout.PAGE_END); 
    frame.add(txtArea, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
            frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: please post the HelloActionListener class

Comment: if you dont have one, what is this doing in your code: ***HelloActionListener hlisten = new HelloActionListener(txtArea);***  ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you want to put "Hello" in your text area when the top button is pressed. Then you need to define your `HelloActionListener` as below:

```
private static class HelloActionListener implements ActionListener {

    private JTextArea textArea;
    public HelloActionListener(JTextArea textArea) {
        this.textArea = textArea;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        textArea.setText("Hello");
    }
}
```

The rest of your code is kind of messy but should work, however, you don't need to make the frame to be visible twice.

**UPDATE**

But I do think your code should be something like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends JFrame {

    public MyApplication() {
        setTitle("Listeners");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JTextArea txtArea = new JTextArea();
        HelloActionListener hlisten = new HelloActionListener(txtArea);
        JButton bl = new JButton("TOP");
        bl.addActionListener(hlisten);
        JButton b2 = new JButton("LEFT");
        ActionListener rightListener = e -> {
            txtArea.setText("Yes,let's go Left");
        };
        b2.addActionListener(rightListener);
        JButton b3 = new JButton("RIGHT");
        b3.addActionListener(e -> {
            txtArea.setText("Sorry, we cant go Right");
        });

        JButton b4 = new JButton("Bottom");
        b4.addActionListener(hlisten);

        add(bl, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(b2, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        add(b3, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        add(b4, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        add(txtArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new MyApplication();
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    private class HelloActionListener implements ActionListener {

        private JTextArea textArea;
        public HelloActionListener(JTextArea textArea) {
            this.textArea = textArea;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
            textArea.setText("Hello from " + button.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I already had that class but was not working. I had the following instead:

    `public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        JButton x = (JButon) e.getSource();
        area.setText("Hello Folks by button: " + x.getText());`

Comment: Is there any way to print the button which pressed too  ?

Comment: @feedoxx, so what you wanna do exactly, can you describe it? Since I don't think we even need a `HelloActionListener`

Comment: Unless there is a really compelling reason, you should extend JPanel, not JFrame. Your main method creates the frame, then creates your extended panel and adds it to the frame.

Comment: I want -> if you press the top and the bottom buttons to print "Hello", if you press the RIGHT to print «Sorry, we cant go Right» and if you press the left, to print  «Yes, let`s go Left».

Comment: @feedoxx That's what your code does. Unless you want to distinguish which button the press comes from, then just use `e.getSource()`.

Comment: @FredK I don't see a difference why you have to extend `JPanel` just for this demo and indeed I am using the main method to create the MyApplication which is a frame. And I think it's perfectly fine even if this is the main frame of an application.

Comment: @feedoxx I added some code in `HelloActionListener` that will also print which button it's called on.

Comment: @KeqiangLi I much appreciated your time! Thank you very much, you help me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the first `frame.setVisible(true);` in your code - you are calling that again right at the end. But your panels are all zero size. You need to call `frame.pack();` before you set it visible.  Note also that all of that (the GUI stuff) should be done from the Event Dispatch Thread, not from your main thread.

Comment: Yes, i had forgotten to remove the first frame.setVisible(true).
I am now learning in school and the teacher had no HelloActionListener class in the example! So...